# How to validate fields server side during user creation with Firebase Auth?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase Auth to create a new user, but I want to validate some fields (pattern matching) using Firestore Security Rules before creating a new account. How can I do that?

In the completion handler for the createUser(withEmail: , password:) function, I am performing some writes to Firestore on successful account creation.

I am facing a problem where sometimes the writes to Firestore may not be successful due to Firestore Secuity Rules (Pattern matching). In this case the write fails but the new user account is still created (since writes are being attempted in completion handler).

```
// Create User Method - Firebase Auth & Swift

Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (result, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    } else { 
                        let userName = [
                            userName:self.userNameTextField.text!
                        ]

// Writing field Data to Firestore

Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(self.userNameTextField.text!).setData(userName) {(err) in
                            if err != nil {

// Rather than throwing a fatalError, how can I ensure new account creation is cancelled so that feedback can be given on the issue with entered field data?                              

fatalError()
                            }
```

I want to ensure a user account is not created in case writes to Firestore are unsuccessful due to a conflict with Firestore Security Rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication doesn't have any security rules.  There's currently no way to check if incoming account properties are valid before a user gets created.  Security rules only apply to data read and written directly to Cloud Firestore (or Realtime Database, or Cloud Storage) from a mobile or web client.

The only thing you could do is use a [Cloud Functions auth trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) to check the account properties after it was created, then delete or deactivate the account if something is wrong.

Comment: I have considered this. I can use this trigger to check if there are corresponding writes for the uid in Firestore, and can delete/disable account in case there aren't. However, the problem with this is - how do I let the user know about the issue? Obviously I would want to pinpoint the exact issue with the exact field on the client side, and allow the user to fix the field before trying to click on the sign up button again.

Comment: There's no easy solution.  You'll have to build some infrastructure for that.  Use Cloud Messaging or write a document they can read later.

Comment: Thanks Doug! Figured something out and in the process of trying it -

I can break the sign up process into 2 steps. The first step can ask the users to input email & password which is validated automatically by Firebase Auth. Once account creation is successful, I can navigate to the next screen and ask them to input other details which can be validated with Firestore Security Rules.

It's not perfect, but it seemed like the easiest to implement and as near perfect as can be - specially given I'm just starting out coding!

Thanks for your help :)